# Как скомпилировать драйвер без Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c, драйвер

У меня не получается скомпилировать драйвер правильно на Visual Studio. А как скомпилировать просто без Visual Studio? В принципе я нашел на хабрахабр [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/40466/), но похоже она написана для win xp (2008 г), по ней скомпилировать можно так:

> После этого запускаем установленный build environment (это командная
>   строка с заданными переменными окружения для компиляции драйвера; она
>   входит в WDK, и запустить ее можно как-то так:
>   «Пуск->Программы->Windows Driver Kits->....->Build
>   Environments->WindowsXP->Windows XP x86 Checked Build Environment»).
>   Переходим в директорию, куда мы положили файл с драйвером (у меня это
>   C:\Drivers\TestDriver) с помощью команды cd (у меня команда выглядит
>   следующим образом: cd C:\Drivers\TestDriver) и набираем команду build.

Но для Win 10 то такого я не нашел.

Comment: Малость не удобно вопрос читать. Уберите скроллинг.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557573(v=vs.85).aspx